# Send sms on event_trigger with motion

Tags: raspbian, motion

I build myself a babycam using [this](http://blog.alexwilde.net/make-a-raspberry-pi-baby-monitor/) article. I start motion on raspberryPi startup like [here](http://opentechguides.com/how-to/article/raspberry-pi/5/raspberry-pi-auto-start.html). My next intention is to send a sms to my smartphone if motion is detected. On [this](http://www.lavrsen.dk/foswiki/bin/view/Motion/MotionGuideBasicFeatures#Sending_SMS_at_start_of_event) site I found out that this is possible.

```
#change to suit your needs:
#location of 'sms-client' binary
SMS_CLIENT="/usr/bin/sms_client"
#Destination sms number
TO="12345"

#Don't change anything below this line
$SMS_CLIENT $TO "Motion detected $1"
```

Do you have any idea what could be meant by

```
location of 'sms-client' binary
```

I have no idea what the file /usr/bin/sms_client should look like.

Comment: I'm afraid it's just a generic call to a binary file. Depending on the hardware you use for connecting to a mobile network the details might differ. Basically you cannot send and SMS "just so". You must either use a hardware device with a SIM card which has capabilities to send SMSes (read: either prepaid credit or a contract with a telecom), or use an SMS gateway. The conditions for either will vary considerably between countries and operators.

Comment: I heard that this is possible using MQTT? You know something about this?

Comment: I agree with @techraf  Side note, I've used python and a gmail account to send text messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using a push messaging service such as pushover.net instead of SMS?   That's what I use for my alerts.